# Why/How these names have different grammatical endings: Marija - Natalija

Tags: дательный-падеж

Why/How these names have different grammatical endings: Marija - Natalija?
Or do they have the same endings in Dative case? Could somebody give me all 6 singular case endings for these two names for women, please.

Answer (score 8):

```
Nom:  Мария    Наталья  
Gen:  Марии    Натальи  
Dat:  Марии    Наталье  
Acc:  Марию    Наталью  
Inst: Марией   Натальей
Prp:  Марии    Наталье
```

The endings differ indeed: *Мария* belongs to declension 1-7a while *Наталья* belongs to 1-6a

Note that both names have complementary forms (*Ма́рья* and *Ната́лия*), accordingly, which do decline similarly to *Наталья* and *Мария* (*Наталия* and *Мария* both belong to 1-7a; *Наталья* and *Марья* both belong to 1-6a).

Before the orthography reform of 1917, both words ended in *iѣ* in both dative and prepositive.

Comment: Interestingly enough, all those endings are completely identical if diminutive version of each name is looked at, namely Маша and Наташа.